# How do I change default wiki versions to Diamondback?

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I notice that some wiki pages using the `<<Version()>>` macro still display the Cturtle version by default. Since Diamondback is the current official release, I'd prefer that version, instead.

Examples:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_view
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9709/how-do-i-change-default-wiki-versions-to-diamondback?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can only be done globally.  I have changed the global default to diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-04-12**:
Thanks, Ken!